# CSS ellipsis of Roboto web font aligned to vertical middle on Android

Tags: android, css, mobile-website, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am working on a *mobile web* application with Roboto webfont and I have a very strange behavior when ellipsizing text.

When I ellipsize text on a desktop browser, this is what I get:

[image]

but on my Galaxy S2, the ellipsis is **aligned to the vertical middle of the line**

[image]

The problem happens on many phones, but not on all of them.

If I remove the webfont import, the ellipsis is ok on both phone and desktop (but then of course I don't use Roboto).

Here is a very straight forward code sample that reproduces the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .ellipsed-text{
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow:ellipsis;
            display: block;
            width:100px;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            font-family: 'Roboto';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="ellipsed-text">test test test test test test test</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Is it my css? Is it a webkit bug? Is there a bug in Google's Roboto webfont?**

Comment: Not reproducible. The code posted uses a web font, so the result should be the same on all browsers (unless web fonts are disabled), and this produces normal ellipsis. You should test what “…” (or `&hellip;`) in content produces in your environment and test (and identify the tested environments). The effect of `text-overflow: ellipsis` may differ from an actual ellipsis character.